# In Webmin (BIND DNS), how do I make ns1.xx.com, ns2.xx.com point to 2 different IPs for multiple domains

Tags: domain, ip, nameserver

I have multiple domains which list as:

- domain.com
- domain.org
- domain.biz
- domain.mobi

and I also have 2 IP addresses which are:

- 46.4.198.15
- 46.4.198.16

The server IP is:

- 46.4.198.1

Now, I want to set them up to be able to work with the domains I have, which of course has to point to the `ns1.domain.com` and `ns2.domain.com`, however I want to set them up in Webmin, which the nameservers will be pointed as:

- ns1.domain.com --> 46.4.198.15
- ns2.domain.com --> 46.4.198.16

Then all domains will point to `ns1.domain.com` and `ns2.domain.com`. I have no idea how to do so.

**EDIT:**

Okay, I've managed to install BIND DNS module for Webmin, I have done the following:

1. Created **master zone** (domain.com).
2. Created 2 nameservers in **Name Server Records**

   1. `domain.com. -> ns1.domain.com`
   2. `domain.com. -> ns2.domain.com`
3. Created 3 addresses in **Address Records**

   1. `domain.com. -> 46.4.198.1`
   2. `ns1.domain.com. -> 46.4.198.15`
   3. `ns1.domain.com. -> 46.4.198.16`

I've also done it to the following other domains, but they all point to `ns1.domain.com` and `ns2.domain.com`, yet I still don't see my DNS being propagated, it's been 3+ days. Even [What's my DNS](http://www.whatsmydns.net/) has reported my DNS is not propagated yet. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will need to register those nameservers at the registrar of your example.com. As for the webmin part, after registering your nameservers at your domain name registrar -- you'll want to log into Virtualmin, select your "example.com" domain, click Server Configuration -> DNS Records, and create a new "A - IPv4 Address" record for ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com.

Lastly, you'll want to tell Virtualmin to use your nameservers when it generates NS records for new Virtual Servers that it creates. You can do that by going into 'System Settings' -> 'Server Templates' -> 'Default Settings' -> 'BIND DNS Domain', and set 'Master DNS server hostname' as well as 'Additional manually configured nameservers'.

Ref: http://www.virtualmin.com/documentation

Comment: Virtualmin isn't Webmin.

Comment: Ofcourse yes, webmin is only for system administration and virtualmin is a webmin module and you will definitely need it if you are planning to host multiple virtualdomains in your server.

Comment: But Virtualmin isn't free isn't it?

Comment: Only the pro version is priced one and there is a GPL version which you can download/install without any cost. You may need to install Usermin first before installing virtualmin.

Comment: I can't seem to install Virtualmin on Ubuntu server 11.04 (64bit).

Comment: You may need to ask this one as a separate question as this has no relevance on the actually asked question.

Comment: Please read my question again, I have edited it. No one seems to post any answers, except you.

Comment: So, the server side setup is complete. The other things you need to check are 1) Did you registered the NSs at your registrar with these IPs ? 2) Did you added the A record for ns1/ns2 at the nameservers of domain.com (unless it is also using ns1/ns2.domain.com) so that the NSs will resolve.

Comment: Yes, all domains point to ns1.domain.com and ns2.domain.com. You can see what I've done in my edited post.

Comment: Ok, what about the registrar cross check.? Are the NSs properly registered with the IPs.? So far the settings seems ok and If you can provide the domain name(unless you don't want to) I can cross check it.

Comment: Is it okay if I could add you on MSN? I prefer this way so I can communicate better, if it's okay?

Comment: I'm in the discussion now.

Comment: Hi, As discussed, please check this with your registrar as it more seems like some error in your registrar end.

Comment: I've done it myself, there was a problem with the `/etc/network/interfaces` since the two IP addresses were not activated, now it works. Thanks for trying to help me, so I'll accept your answer anyway.

Comment: Glad to hear that you sorted out everything yourself :) Have a nice day.